# Nuxt.js's nested view with custom path(URL)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the following directory structure within Nuxt:

```
myProjectRoot/
--| pages/
----| products/
------| _id.vue
----| collections/
------| _id.vue
------| index.vue
----| collections.vue
```

The structure gives me the following matches respectively:

```
[u1] localhost/collections    --> [c1] pages/collections.vue
[u2] localhost/collections/10 --> [c2] pages/collections/_id.vue
[u3] localhost/products/100   --> [c3] pages/products/_id.vue
```

Now I want to display `[c3]` component at `[c1]` as a child view(the same way as `[c2]`), but retain url the same as `[u3]`. How can I do that?

Comment: Not quite clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov The purpose is to move the information block from [c3] separate page into [c1] component as a child component (using <nuxt-child>). Like a modal window or so. At the same time [u3] must be kept intact.

Comment: Then make it a `child-component` and use `conditional rendering`. You don't need to have separate page or route for that.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Making it `child-component` is not a problem. But I'm not sure how should I tell Nuxt (e.g. using `conditional rendering`) that user would see the `child-component` only when href is `http://site/products/100` (not `http://site/collections/10/products/100` nor what ever else). It is essential requirement to have a separate unique uri for the product item of online e-shop.

Comment: To clarify (I hope) a little bit more. `[c2]` is organically settled at the `[c1]` page's code and has respective relative path (navigation from `/collections` to `/collections/10`) because of Nuxt's intrinsic requirement of files structure. At the same time in order to have totally independent uri you have to create corresponding file structure inside `/pages` directory.